# Recursively checking the validity of a number

Tags: c++

How would you write a program that will recursively check whether the given input is a valid floating-point value in C++.

Comment: Did you start with stepping through the code in your debugger? It should help you figure out where the problem is.

Comment: But ".1" is a valid floating point number.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the problem is with this line :

```
nextChar= strExp.at(first + 1);
```

because if the size of string is 1 it become strExp(1)

```
char nextChar=' ';
if(first+1<length)
   nextChar= strExp.at(first + 1);
```

And also It's better to pass string by refrence not value

```
int endInt(const string& strExp, int first)
{
//...
}
```